# View.invisible not working

Tags: android, hide, spinner

I need to hide a spinner once the child activity is finished. I have used `View.INVISIBLE` in the `OnActivityResult()` of the parent.

This is the code:

```
Spinner gSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Sorter);
gSpinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

But this doesn't work.The spinner remains intact.
please help me out with this..

Comment: Are you sure that code is being called?

Comment: there is no way, it doesn't work. Check if this code is being called.

Comment: @Eric and Kamal... thank you for the help...The code is being reached. I had overlooked the fact that there was another function being called from OnActivityResult() which redrew the spinner.

Answer (score 0):

```
setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

can be used on the spinner to make it invisible without taking any pixels on the screen

Comment: [`View.GONE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE) and [`View.INVISIBLE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#INVISIBLE) are two different things. It would seem the OP wants the `Spinner` to be invisible but continue to take up space.

Answer (score 0):

R u defining Spinner id in OnActivityResult(). If yes, call it in onCreate and then setVisibility in OnActivityResult(). Also check all attributes of Spinner in your xml file properly

Answer (score 0):

Do not create the another instance in onActivityResult.

first of all

Declare `Spinner gSpinner;` as globally.

and Declare

```
gSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Sorter);
```

in `onCreate()` method.

and finally call

```
 gSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

in `onActivityResult()`